# Highchart Series Data Format for Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm attempting to use Highcharts Series function to create a combination bar/line chart, but I'm having trouble just getting the series to display. There's nothing in the API about how to format data from Google Spreadsheets when using series so I took a stab at it and the chart does not display:

```js
$(function() {
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    chart: {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      shadow: false,
      width: null,
      height: null
    }
  });
  $('#ms-96-enrollment').highcharts({
    series: [{
      type: 'bar',
      data: [{
        googleSpreadsheetKey: '1Nx8zcIi0ULxytLmra0A9N11-llzJCDVH2-7SbK_k5-U',
        startColumn: 0,
        endColumn: 1,
        startRow: 0,
        googleSpreadsheetWorksheet: 7
      }],
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
</head>
<div>
  <div id="ms-96-enrollment"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts is a little bit misleading having two "data"s - in series and on top level. The first is used for javascript point arrays while the later is for facilitating adding existing datasets (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#data)

Thus for Google Spreadsheets

```
$('#ms-96-enrollment').highcharts({
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },
  data: {
    googleSpreadsheetKey: '1Nx8zcIi0ULxytLmra0A9N11-llzJCDVH2-7SbK_k5-U',
    startColumn: 0,
    endColumn: 1,
    startRow: 0,
    googleSpreadsheetWorksheet: 7
  },
  title: {
    text: 'My google data'
  },
  yAxis: {},
  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      enabled: true,
    }
  }
});
```

Here's the sample based on your data http://plnkr.co/edit/aIqMVcaeyYEbHcdxoMaT

**UPDATE**

If you need to show multiple series add extra columns and specify series:

```
data: {
  googleSpreadsheetKey: '1Nx8zcIi0ULxytLmra0A9N11-llzJCDVH2-7SbK_k5-U',
  startColumn: 0,
  endColumn: 2,
  startRow: 0,
  googleSpreadsheetWorksheet: 7
}

...

series: [{
  type: 'bar'
}, {
  type: 'line'
}]
```

Here's the updated sample http://plnkr.co/edit/UQprlugBtUXQX9OffUm4?p=preview

Comment: So I know how to format the data if it's just one set of data, but I want to add several data sets so I can display each differently in a [http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/combining-chart-types](combo chart).

Comment: You got it! 2 answers 2 days in a row. I should just start messaging you directly.

Comment: Welcome :-) BTW if your series are of different units you can add multiple X or Y axis and reference them from series as you do for plain point data series (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes)